# MySQL/PHP Prepared statement insert error

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a page designed to add a new user to a program. When the create button is clicked, the info is sent via POST to my php script to run some login, encrypt the password and insert the data into MySQL using prepared statements. However, I keep getting the following error and am not sure why:

**Prepare failed: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1**

My Script:

```
<?php

include("inc.php");

if ((isset($_POST['firstname'])) and (isset($_POST['lastname'])) and (isset($_POST['company'])) and (isset($_POST['statusflag'])) and (isset($_POST['username'])) and (isset($_POST['password'])) and (isset($_POST['passwordConfirm']))) {

    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $department = $_POST['department'];
    $statusflag = $_POST['statusflag'];
    $admin = $_POST['admin'];
    $revoked = $_POST['revoked'];
    $login = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    $passConfirm = $_POST['passwordConfirm'];

} else {

    echo "Values did not save. Please try again.";
}



if ($pass == $passConfirm) {


    $passEnc = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


    if ($conn->connect_errno) {
        echo "There was a problem connecting to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
    }


    if (!($sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sched_users(login, password, firstname, lastname, email, phone, company, department, admin, statusflag, revoked) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?"))) {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
    }


    if (!$sql->bind_param("sssssssiiss", $login, $passEnc, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $phone, $company, $department, $admin, $statusflag, $revoked)) {
        echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $sql->errno . ") " . $sql->error;
    }


    if (!$sql->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $sql->errno . ") " . $sql->error;
    }


    $sql->close();
    $conn->close();


} else {

    echo "Passwords don't match. Please try again.";
}

?>
```

My Table has the same exact columns in the same order except for the first column (id) which is the auto-increment primary key. This column shouldn't need to be included in the Insert as MySQL will handling the auto-increment on its end.

All help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: `)` in the wrong place / missing.

Comment: @JonStirling Nah he's just missing it. He's grouping his conditions with parenthesis.

Comment: @Daerik Spotted and updated comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First error:

```
if (!($sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sched_users(login, password, firstname, lastname, email, phone, company, department, admin, statusflag, revoked) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?"))) {
```

check final of `if`:

```
")))
```

remplace with:

```
if (!($sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sched_users(login, password, firstname, lastname, email, phone, company, department, admin, statusflag, revoked) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")))
```

Comment: Which makes it a typo, which is one of the close vote reasons...

Comment: Yes it was a typo. Thank you guys!